# If hasClass then addClass to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

**Original post:**
Why doesn't this simple script work?

```
if ($('#navigation > ul > li > ul > li > a').hasClass('.active')) {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass(".active");
}
```

**EDIT:**

This won't hide the H1:

```
if ($('#content h1').hasClass('aktiv')) {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Only this will:

```
if ($('#content h1').hasClass('aktiv')) {
    $('#content h1').hide();
}
```

Why can't I use the (this)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The dot is not part of the class name. It's only used in CSS/jQuery selector notation. Try this instead:

```
if ($('#navigation a').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
}
```

If `$(this)` refers to that anchor, you have to change it to `$('#navigation a')` as well because the if condition does not have jQuery callback scope.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could use:

```
if ($('#navigation a').is(".active")) {
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: $('#navigation a.active').parent().parent().addClass('active') would do the same thing. The conditional is something that can be handled with the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change the condition to `if ($(this).hasClass('active'))`

Also, `hasClass` and `addClass` take *classnames*, not selectors.
Therefore, you shouldn't include a `.`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$(this)` since jQuery doesn't know what it is there. You seem to be overcomplicating things. You can do `$('#content h1.aktiv').hide()`. There's no reason to test to see if the class exists.

Comment: I need a script, that finds out if there is an object with the class ".aktiv". If the class is found, the parents parents parent should be given the same class. The Edited part, with the if-sentence, is just something I stumpled upon - a bug, if you like, that I just wanted to hear you guys.

Comment: You can do $('#content h1.aktiv').parent().parent().addClass('aktiv') without conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that does not work is because `this` has no specific meaning inside of an if statement, you will have to go back to a level of scope where `this` is defined (a function).

For example:

```
$('#element1').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id')); // logs "element1"

    if ($('#element2').hasClass('class')) {
        console.log($(this).attr('id')); // still logs "element1"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using WordPress, you can use something like:

```
if (jQuery('.dropdown-menu li').hasClass('active')) {
    jQuery('.current-menu-parent').addClass('current-menu-item');
}
```