# if hasclass then add class to a separate selector (not parent)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw this stack: [If hasClass then addClass to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208051/if-hasclass-then-addclass-to-parent) which almost answered my question, but in my case, I want to add the class to a selector that is NOT a parent.

I have several fields in my form that all have the class contact on them. When the form is submitted, the error class is added to any field that is empty. We need the label that we are using for the wrapped fields to also turn red if any of the containing fields are red. Right now, it stays black. So the script I require will check to see if any of those fields have an error attached, and then turn the label red as well. Anyone have any ideas?

http://link.rubiconglobal.com/l/263882/2017-03-24/7ssj

The link above is where you can view this form in action. My script I attempted as the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#pardot-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
if ($('#263882_11763pi_263882_11763').is(".error")) {
document.getElementById('label2').addClass = 'error';
}
</script>
```

Comment: can u add an image which labels you expecting to turn red?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You need to add color for empty?

Comment: I have added the following: 

<script type="text/javascript">
        $( "#pardot-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
if ($('#263882_11763pi_263882_11763').is(".error")) {
    document.getElementById('label2').addClass = 'error';
}
    </script>

I cannot add an image. The last question is the one that I want to turn red.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#pardot-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
      if ($('#263882_11763pi_263882_11763').is(".error")) {
        $(this).addClass('error')
      }
    });
  });
    </script>
```

Comment: This doesn't add the class to just label2

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#pardot-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
      if ($('p').hasClass("error")) {
        document.getElementById('label2').addClass = 'error';
      }
    });
  });
    </script>
```

Comment: This didn't work. I just need the .contact has errors done.